# Adding image thumbnails to grid rows in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to add images to my current grid. Right now it displays the names of articles and what I'd like is to add a unique thumbnail above each articles name. My code is currently replacing the article name entirely and returning a broken image.

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
store: gridStore,
id:'my_grid',
stateful: true,
listeners : {
             'celldblclick' : function(iView, iCellEl, iColIdx, iStore, iRowEl,iRowIdx, iEvent) {
                   var textbody = gridStore.getAt(iRowIdx).data.id;
                   $('#articleBody').html(textbody);
                   $('#header').html('<strong> Uncategorized </strong>')
            }
},
columns: [
    {
        text     : 'Article Name',
        flex     : 1,
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex: 'company',
        dataIndex:'image',
        renderer : function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex,colIndex, store)
        {
            return   "<img src='"+value+"' />";
        }
    }, 
],
height: 500,         
renderTo: 'gridPanel',
viewConfig: {
    stripeRows: true
}
});
```

Also, is it possible to set multiple attributes within DataIndex? I need both company and image as indexes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multiple dataIndexes, but you can just easily expand your `renderer()` to add the extra HTML to show both the title and image in whatever style and configuration you'd like. You're already getting the `record` passed to the renderer, so simply grab the value from the property in the record that you'd like:

```
renderer : function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex,colIndex, store)  {
    return   record.get( 'company' ) + "<img src='"+value+"' />";
}
```

Comment: if I have my data store defined like so:

`[
['company','id','image'],
['company','id','image'],
['company','id','image'],
['company','id','image'],
['company','id','image'],
['company','id','image'],
];`

With image being an url to the image I want to load, how would I phrase my renderer return statement?

Comment: I tried
`return record.get('company') + "<img src='record.get('image')'/>";`
but it only returns the company id.

Comment: Does your store mappings match the data returned? Looks like it's off an index or two.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that is setting `dataIndex` twice will just result in the `dataIndex` being set to 'image', because the second one will replace the first. As far as I know, there is no way to have a single column display multiple data values. You should probably just place them in separate columns.

The reason your article name is missing completely is because, as I explained above, the `dataIndex` is set to 'image'. As for the broken image, it is possible the path you have doesn't work. You should verify that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
{
    text     : 'Article Name',
    flex     : 1,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex: 'company',
    renderer: function(value, metadata, record) {
        return Ext.String.format('{0} <img height="20" width="20" src="{1}"></img>', value, record.data.image);
    }
},
```

If dataIndex is different than 'company' then you can use following in renderer

```
return Ext.String.format('{0} <img height="20" width="20" src="{1}"></img>', record.data.company, record.data.image);
```